# How to inquire the ith term in a table at postgreql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

`alldp` charcter varraying

```
"{K409,K358,K353,L059,R100,L050,K610,K352,K425,K661,I841,I848,Z433}"
```

I want to inquire the second term (K358), So I write like this `select alldp[2] from table;` 
but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation `[2]` is only valid for arrays. But your column is a varchar column, not an array.

You need to first convert your string into an array using the the same function that I have shown you [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27128537/330315):

```
select (string_to_array(alldp, ','))[2]
from the_table;
```

Comment: thank you very much,i want to find others in another table that is the same as the seconde term, before ,i write like this " select * from table1 ,table2 where table1.dp= table2.alldp[2]",so i should replace" select * from table1 ,table2 where table1.dp=table2.string_to_array(alldp,',')[2]"?